# Co-variance of linear combination of random variables - rearrange

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been posed the following question:
[image]

I'm aware of how to calculate $cov(X,Y)$ but how do I calculate $cov(X,Z)$?
I have attempted to re-arrange the linear combination to: $-Y= X-Z$ and tried calculating $cov(X,Z)$ from there to no success..

Comment: Do you know certain properties of covariance?

Comment: i've tried re-arranging the derivation for co-variance to be in terms of $-Y = X-Z$ to no luck.. unless there is some property im missing..

Comment: $\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$There is a property that lets you expand $\Cov(X, X + Y)$. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Covariance_of_linear_combinations.

Comment: i still can't see how using any of the 'co-variance for linear combinations' would help in this case? they all require knowing other co-variances not given in this question..

Comment: never mind, i eventually work it out using another example, thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$**Hint:** We have $$\Cov(X,\color{blue}{X} \color{teal}{+}\color{red}{Y}) = \Cov(X,\color{blue}{X}) \color{teal}{+} \Cov(X,\color{red}{Y}).$$

Now, if we know the value of $\Var(X)$, then what can we say about $\Cov(X,X)$? Also, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then what is the value of $\Cov(X,Y)$?

Comment: thanks for that! took me a while but I figured it out with your link help!

Comment: You're welcome!